# Why is not working EF Core retry on failure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, interceptor, ef-core-3.1

I've configured my db context to retry on failure this way:

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions => {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 10,
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null);
            });
```

Also I have configured following interceptor:

```cs
public class DbCommandFailureInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        private int retryCount = 2;

        public override async Task<InterceptionResult<int>> NonQueryExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            Throw(command);
            return result;
        }

        public override async Task<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            Throw(command);
            return result;
        }

        private void Throw(DbCommand command)
        {
            if (!(command.CommandText.Contains("serverproperty")
        || command.CommandText.Contains("_MigrationHistory"))
        && retryCount > 0) {
                --retryCount;
                throw SqlExceptionFaker.Error10053;
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically I'm expecting when fetching entities from the database to hit Throw method 3 times, 2 with throwing exception and last time without throwing it.
But actually there is no retry on failure and after first exception execution is getting stopped.
What am I doing wrong?

I have such helper for resilient transactions:

```cs
public class ResilientTransaction
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        private ResilientTransaction(DbContext context) =>
            _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        public async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action)
        {
            var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () => {
                using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync()) {
                    await action();
                    await transaction.CommitAsync();
                }
            });
        }

        public static ResilientTransaction New(DbContext context) =>
            new ResilientTransaction(context);
    }
```

And here is the way I am executing it:

```cs
await ResilientTransaction.New(_dbContext).ExecuteAsync(async () => {
                    _dbContext.Tenants.Add(new Tenant());
                    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                });
```

Comment: Are you getting a failure?  Why would you be getting a failure?

Comment: I guess if retryCount == 0 should throw the Exception, otherwise throw will not be handled.

Comment: @jdweng sure I'm getting an exception and nothing is getting saved to the database for some reason, that's the most frustrating part, and this is the question - why does it fail?

Comment: Did you check the log files on the SQL Server?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0

Comment: @jdweng can you please point more specifically to which log files should I pay attention to?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server (UseSqlServer)?  The server has a LDF file (the MDF is the database) which are the log files.  Using SQL Server Management Studio you can view the logs.

Comment: just checked and it looks like that no logs are getting generated during this code execution

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: this is because this particular implementation of retry strategy retries only for specific exceptions (like timeout for sql) .

If you want retries work for your test you need to throw these specific exceptions (which could be not an easy task with some hacks) or better write your own custom retry strategy and use it in db context, but for testing only!